# Subtracting minimums bound

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider $|\min f-\min g|$. Can we bound this in terms of $\min f-g$ or $\min |f-g|$?

I know that $\min f+\min g\leq \min f+g$ and I know that $\min g=-\max (-g)$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, no.  Let $f=(0,0,1000,0,0), g=(0,1000,0,0,0)$.  Then $|\min f - \min g|=0$ but $\min (f-g) = -1000$ and $|\min (f-g)|=1000$.  This should help you think about examples for bounds that somebody might suggest.

Comment: But that $1000$ is not expressed anywhere in the minima of $f$ and $g$.